# Java Selenium error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument is of an illegal type: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20"

Tags: java, selenium

I have element in PageObjects class that I want to click by JavascriptExecuter in Functions class

PageObject class:

```
package com.objects;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class PageObject {
    protected WebDriver driver;

    public PageObject(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

PageObjects class:

```
package com.objects;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

import java.util.List;

public class PageObjects extends PageObject{

    public WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy (xpath = "//label[@class='mat-checkbox-layout']")
    public WebElement isRequiredCheckbox;

    public PageObjects(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }
}
```

Functions class:

```
package com.functions;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import java.util.List;

public class Functions {
    public WebDriver driver;

    public WebElement jsClick(WebDriver driver, WebElement element){
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
        return element;
    }
}
```

when I'm calling `jsClick` method in main class, it returns error

```
functions.jsClick(driver, pageObjects.isRequiredCheckbox);
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument is of an illegal type: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.WebElementToJsonConverter.apply(WebElementToJsonConverter.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:477)
    at com.functions.Functions.jsClick(Functions.java:52)
    at com.testDefinition.MainTest.addNewNoun(MainTest.java:300)
```

But if I declare element path in main class, it's working without error

```
WebElement isRequiredCheckbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class='mat-checkbox-layout']"));
functions.jsClick(driver, isRequiredCheckbox);
```

But I want to use element path from PageObjects class

Main class:

```
package com.testDefinition;

import com.data.UserData;
import com.functions.Functions;
import com.objects.PageObjects;
import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.List;

public class MainTest {
    private PageObjects pageObjects;
    private UserData userData;

    private Functions functions = new Functions();
    private final WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    private WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

    @Given("Open website")
    public void runWebDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.geckodriver.driver", "/usr/local/bin/geckodriver");
        driver.get("website link");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Then("Login by Admin")
    public void login() {
        pageObjects = new PageObjects(driver);
        userData = new UserData();

        pageObjects.inputLogin.sendKeys(userData.Admin);
        pageObjects.inputPassword.sendKeys(userData.AdminPass);
        pageObjects.submitButton.click();
    }

    @And("Start add new noun")
    public void addNewNoun() throws Throwable{
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(pageObjects.addNewNounBtn));

        List <WebElement> qaCodesList = pageObjects.nounQACodesList;
        List <WebElement> preservCodesList = pageObjects.nounPreservCodesList;
        List <WebElement> measuerUnitsList = pageObjects.measureUnitList;

        String qaCodeText = "Test";

        pageObjects.addNewNounBtn.click();
        pageObjects.inputNounModifName.sendKeys(functions.generateNounModifName());

        Thread.sleep(500);
        pageObjects.nounQACodesListBtn.click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        functions.getAddNounListCode(qaCodesList, qaCodeText);

        pageObjects.nounPreservCodesListBtn.click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        preservCodesList.get(2).click();

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(pageObjects.addSpecificationBtn));
        pageObjects.addSpecificationBtn.click();
        pageObjects.specificationName.sendKeys(functions.generateNounModifName());

        Thread.sleep(500);
        pageObjects.measureUnitsListBtn.click();

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(measuerUnitsList));
        measuerUnitsList.get(3).click();

        //WebElement isRequiredCheckbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class='mat-checkbox-layout']"));
        functions.jsClick(driver, pageObjects.isRequiredCheckbox);
    }
}
```

Comment: Things should work in specific manner. Create a getter method in PageObjects class e.g. `Public WebElement getRequiredCheckbox()
{
 return isRequiredCheckbox;
}` and pass this element as parameter in `functions.jsClick(driver, new PageObjects(driver).getRequiredCheckbox());` 
Assuming you are doing PageFactory element initialisation in appropriate way.

Comment: @Nik Thanks for answer, but it shows same error :)

Comment: I would remove all your `driver` fields from all provided classes since they do not participate in logic.

Comment: What versions of FFx, FF driver and Selenium bindings do you use?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Firefox version: 69.0.2,    geckodriver version: 0.26.0

Comment: And what is selenium library version?

Comment: @AlexeyR.Selenium version: 3.11.0

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your PageObject class is initializing PageFactory or not. if PageFactory is not initialized, your webelement will be null.

```
   public class PageObject
{
   public PageObject(WebDriver driver){

      PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
   }

}
```

Comment: Yes, PageFactory initialized in PageObject class

Comment: Edited question. Pointed PageObject class on top

Comment: Please add main class to your question, there is no problem with the code you have shared

Comment: Added main class below of question

Comment: pageObjects is not initialized, pageObjects=new PageObjects(driver) , please try and let me know

Comment: Sorry, but other main class methods were hidden :). `pageObjects` was initialized in `login` method before `addNewNoun` method. As you can there in addNewNoun method other `pageObjects` elements were called before `functions.jsClick(driver, pageObjects.isRequiredCheckbox);`